# Как збилдить игру в Unity для релиза

Tags: unity3d

Когда делаю билд проекта Unity, то вместо запуска игры сразу, появляется окошко:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я хочу, чтобы открывалась сама игра.
Вот настройки билда. Я не нашел здесь флажков типо "Release" и т.п.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как же быть?

Comment: +1 за слово "збилдить".

Comment: Даже так) Неплохо

Comment: @Igor так вы знаете как мне помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Збилдить, действительно звучит)
А вообще, насколько я помню это выключается в настройках игрока:

PlayerSettings->Settings for PC, Mac and Linux -> Resolution and Presentation -> Display Resolution Dialog -> Disabled

Как то так)

Comment: За ответ спасибо, но что за прикол с этим "збилдить"?) Возможно я что то не так написал?

Comment: Нуу, русский немного специфичен) Совершенная форма глагола начинается с "С", делал - сделал, как следствие транскрипции с английского подчиняются тем же правилам) билдил - сбилдил. В вот "зделал" и "збилдил", ну я не знаю... Но звучит реально весело)

Comment: Кстати, еще по теме вопроса, это окошко, это не "дебажная фигня", это окно позволяющее запустить проект на разных мониторах с разным разрешением (что логично), в нормальной ситуации, если его отключать, то по-хорошему этот выбор надо давать внутри игры (ну и вручную реализовать его), потому что какое разрешение у игры будет по дефолту я даже не скажу)